# how to get POST values in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to customize a script and need to get a POST value from a form using perl. 
I have no background of perl but this is a fairly simple thing so I guess it should not be hard.

This is the php version of the code I would like to have in PERL:

```
<?php
$download = ($_POST['dl']) ? '1' : '0';
?>
```

I know this may not be at all related to the PERL version but it could help I guess clarifying what exactly I am looking to do.

Comment: @vjshah Im not sure if you are being sarcastic, but sure, I just need to know how to get the POST value (from a submitted form) and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in that case please have a look at this simple code: This would help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

sub output_top($);
sub output_end($);
sub display_results($);
sub output_form($);

my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header();

# Output stylesheet, heading etc
output_top($q);

if ($q->param()) {
    # Parameters are defined, therefore the form has been submitted
    display_results($q);
} else {
    # We're here for the first time, display the form
    output_form($q);
}

# Output footer and end html
output_end($q);

exit 0;

# Outputs the start html tag, stylesheet and heading
sub output_top($) {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->start_html(
        -title => 'A Questionaire',
        -bgcolor => 'white');
}

# Outputs a footer line and end html tags
sub output_end($) {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->div("My Web Form");
    print $q->end_html;
}

# Displays the results of the form
sub display_results($) {
    my ($q) = @_;

    my $username = $q->param('user_name');
}

# Outputs a web form
sub output_form($) {
    my ($q) = @_;
    print $q->start_form(
        -name => 'main',
        -method => 'POST',
    );

    print $q->start_table;
    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td('Name:'),
      $q->td(
        $q->textfield(-name => "user_name", -size => 50)
      )
    );

    print $q->Tr(
      $q->td($q->submit(-value => 'Submit')),
      $q->td('&nbsp;')
    );
    print $q->end_table;
    print $q->end_form;
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly good example, and I think I get it, but the current script I am using uses GET/POST values BUT does not include `new CGI`, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: In that case,One method can be use of jQuery to handle post.And you can always include javascript code to perl. print qq(#include the headers jQuery('form_id').submit(function(){ var val=jQuery("id").val();}));

Answer (score 5):

Style advice: you almost never need to assign 0 or 1 to a variable. Simply evaluate the value itself in bool context.

---

In [CGI.pm (CGI)](http://p3rl.org/CGI), the `param` method merges POST and GET parameters, so we need to inspect the request method separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use CGI qw();
my $c = CGI->new;
print $c->header('text/plain');
if ('POST' eq $c->request_method && $c->param('dl')) {
    # yes, parameter exists
} else {
    # no
}
print 'Do not taunt happy fun CGI.';
```

---

With [Plack::Request (PSGI)](http://p3rl.org/Plack%3a%3aRequest), you have different methods for POST (`body_parameters`) and GET (`query_parameters`) in addition to the mixed interface (`parameters`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env plackup
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Plack::Request qw();
my $app = sub {
    my ($env) = @_;
    my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);
    if ($req->body_parameters->get_all('dl')) {
        # yes
    } else {
        # no
    }
    return [200, [Content_Type => 'text/plain'], ['Do not taunt happy fun Plack.']];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start: [The Fool's Guide to CGI.pm,
the Perl module for CGI scripting](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/cgi.html).

This will show you "...how to get the POST value (from a submitted form) and assign it to a variable."

Hope this helps!

Comment: I scanned through it and saw that you can do `param('sample')` now something that I couldnt find was that how to differentiate between GET and POST requests?? I do not want to get `GET` values, ONLY if `POST` is set the value should be assign to $download

Comment: $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
    {#do something here;}

Comment: You can use `CGI.pm`'s `request_method()` to check for a `POST` request, e.g., `my $requestMethod = $cgi->request_method()`.

Answer (score 0):

The above examples are bit complicated. The below code reads POST values into a variable. You can extract Key Value from that. If its GET then its better to use `CGI` module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $FormData = '';
read(STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

## Variable $FormData holds all POST values passed

use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header();
print "$FormData";
```