# Getting data from HTTP POST request with Perl

Tags: perl, http, post, web

How we can fetch data sent via POST request in Perl? Is it similar and easy as in PHP, for instance **$_POST["name"])**? If someone could point me to the websites which will help me to solve this, I will be thankful.

I found [this](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html) but I cannot find nothing like 'receive/fetch HTTP POST data', just 'Posting Form Data', which is not what I need now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get POST values in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088538/how-to-get-post-values-in-perl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're writing Perl scripts for a web server? And you want to know a quick way to get data from the request?

```
use CGI;
```

This was such a core Perl standard 20 years ago. Whole sites consisted of just Perl-CGI scripts.

```
my $q = CGI->new();
if ( $q->param()) { 
    my $name_value = $q->param( 'name' );
}
```

More [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm), [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/cgi.html) and [here](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI).

You can probably look at [Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template) and there are more up-to-date web application platforms. But, if you just want post parameters from a form, `use CGI;`

Comment: I am beginner in Perl/CGI, so thanks for these links and explanations, I'll read them all.

Comment: @Lazar, are you using Apache? If you are, then you might think about [mod_perl](https://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/), which makes web apps more "appy". My last perl job, was a Apache-mod_perl/CGI/Template stack.

Comment: Yes I am using Apache.

Comment: @Lazar: Just for info,You don't have to take care of GET/POST, the sames methods apply for both.

Comment: @Toto, I was thinking about mentioning that, but I thought the tutorial would probably fill that in.